# Problem with a plot for 1D wave equation solution using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I can't properly use `Manipulate` for my solution of a wave equation. Can anyone help me?

I have the wave equation in the form:

```
D[WaveEq[x, t], t, t] == 20*D[WaveEq[x, t], x, x]
```

Initial conditions are:

```
WaveEq[x, 0] == Sin[Pi*x]
Derivative[0, 1][WaveEq][x, 0] == 0
```

Boundary conditions are:

```
WaveEq[0, t] == 0
WaveEq[1, t] == 0
```

It is solved on the range `{x,0,1}` and `{t,0,1}`. The result using `Plot3D` looks like this:
[image: Plot3D solution of a wave equation]

I then try to make a 2D plot with the values of `WaveEq` vs values of `x`. I want the plot to be manipulated with respect to time `t`. I get a blank result for this 2D plot.

Here is the full code:

```
 sol1 = NDSolve[{D[WaveEq[x, t], t, t] == 20*D[WaveEq[x, t], x, x],

   WaveEq[x, 0] == Sin[Pi*x],
   Derivative[0, 1][WaveEq][x, 0] == 0,
   WaveEq[0, t] == 0,
   WaveEq[WaveDistance, t] == 0},
   WaveEq[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]

   Plot3D[WaveEq[x, t] /. sol1, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, t}]

   Manipulate[
   Plot[WaveEq[x, t] /. sol1, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

One correction: the code must also have this line:

```
WaveDistance = 1;
```

Comment: `Here is the full code` when I copied and pasted the full code into my notebook, I get syntax errors.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a line that assigns the value of 1 to WaveDistance that shows up in boundary conditions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line of the `NDSolve` function is missing from the question,

```
WaveEq[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

With it included and `WaveDistance` set equal to `1` (to reproduce the `Plot3D` result), the `Manipulate` function can be made to work with a minor modification,

```
Manipulate[Plot[WaveEq[x, t] /. sol1 /. t -> t0, {x, 0, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t0, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

Another approach is

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[WaveEq[x, t], t, t] == 20*D[WaveEq[x, t], x, x],
    WaveEq[x, 0] == Sin[Pi*x], Derivative[0, 1][WaveEq][x, 0] == 0, WaveEq[0, t] == 0, 
    WaveEq[1, t] == 0}, WaveEq, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}];
Manipulate[Plot[s[t], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
    {t, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Initialization :> (s[t_] := sol[x, t])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked.

Comment: I suggest `With[{waveEq = Head[sol[[1, 1, 2]]]}, Manipulate[  Plot[waveEq[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]` as a simplified version of this answer.

Comment: @m_goldberg  I believe you mean either `{waveEq = Head[sol1[[1, 1, 2]]]}` or `{waveEq = sol}`.  In any case very ingenious (+1).  I had tried `With[{t = t}, Plot ...` inside Manipulate but without success.

Comment: From the point of view of your 1st answer it should be `{waveEq = Head[sol1[[1, 1, 2]]]}`. For your 2nd answer, I would simply write `waveEq = NDSolveValue[...]`, and then `Manipulate[Plot[waveEq[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`. In this form the 2nd answer becomes very elegant.